# Importing multiple product variations in one product display

Tags: commerce, feeds

I have this huge problem I cant understand. 
I import products via feeds....i have mapped excel cvs file....
I can import one product variation to one product display...
But I have 4 product variations and I dont know hot to setup my excel file
because product display and product variation match connect with eachother withunique identifier like sku
but I have here four different skus for 4 variations like for example
22SKU_red
22SKU_orange
22SKU_blue
22SKU_black

Any idea how to set it up to import with excel?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in the context of importing product displays, but in theory you should be able to accomplish this by choosing a character to separate the SKU's, putting all SKU's in single column, and by using the Feeds Tamper plugin "Explode".

The explode tamper plugin cares that your input data is handled as multiple values.

Example XLS file:

```
Product display title | SKU
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Lorem Ipsum           | 22SKU_red|22SKU_orange|22SKU_blue|22SKU_black
Dolor Sit Amet        | 23SKU_red|23SKU_orange
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

**Steps**

1. Separate the SKU's in your Excel file with a certain character, for example a pipe character: "|".
2. Install the module Feeds Tamper. Also enable the Feeds Tamper Admin UI module (included with Feeds Tamper).
3. Go the Tamper page of your feeds importer (/admin/structure/feeds/[importer_id]/tamper).
4. Click "Add plugin" for the "Product: SKU (field_product:sku)" mapper.
5. For the plugin to add, select "Explode". As string separator, choose the character that you used to separate your SKU's. If you followed the example, then this would be the pipe character: "|". See also the image:
   [image: Feeds Tamper "Explode" plugin]